# Checking for updates from network continuously - how?

Tags: java, android, networking

When my phone receives a text message, it will upload it to my database. On the tablet I should get a notification about the new message as soon as possible.

How do I efficiently check for new messages from the database? I don't think a background process that queries the database every few seconds is efficient at all. It will drain the battery and it's huge waste of network.

Answer (score 1):

Have a static BroadcastReceiver in your App as a listener. If a text message comes in the receiver will get started and onReceive() will get called. Now you can invoke a Service/ an Activity to save it to your database and put up a notification.

Here's a nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html) to get you started.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make my point clear. Yes, I know how to listen for incoming messages, but I wanted to know how I can receive them from the database on the tablet. The program on the tablet should be notified as soon as possible after the message has been uploaded to the database.

Comment: Oh then you are looking for GCM. You need to add this functionality to your server as well as in your tablet. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Are you using a ContentProvider as an interface with the DB?